# php + Jquery, upload image in a database record and display it without refreshing next to my record

Tags: jquery, database

i developed a simple web application that deletes games and add games without refreshing the page. everything is working fine with the help of some guys here.
for the goal of training i want to add an extra step and any tips on the best way to do it is appreciated.

i want to add an image next to each record i have displaying an image of the game. i want the user to be able to add game with the capability to upload an image too.
now i am not sure do i just add simply an image input type and upload file?
how will it be store in the database?
can i just add a link for every game displaying the image for that game? 
do i store the image as blob which i have to google what it means or do i save in the table the path where each image is located on my harddisk?

Here is my index.php and add.php delete.php and the dbconfig

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
     <title>title</title>
</head>
 <body>
 <?php
include("dbconfig.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM games";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

  echo "<p class=\"p" .$record['ID']. "\"></br> Game ID: " .$record['ID']. "</br> Game Name: " .$record['Name'].
  "<br /> Game Type: ".$record['Type']. "<br /> Rating: ".$record['Rating']."<br />  Year Released: ".$record['Release Year']."<br /> <br />" ?>
 <a href="#" id="<?php echo $record["ID"]; ?>" class="deletebutton"><img  src="trash.png" alt="delete"/> </a></p>
<?php
 }
?>

 <form name="add" id ="add" action=""  method="post">
 <input class ="gameID" type="hidden" id="ID" name="ID" value = " ' .$record['ID'] . ' " />
 <b>Game Name: </b> <input type="text" id="name" name="name" size=70>
 <b>Game Type:</b> <input type="text" id="type" name="type" size=40>
 <b>Rating: </b> <input type="number"  id="score"  name="score" min="1.0" max="10.0"  step ="0.1"/>
 <b>Year Released: </b> <input type="number"  min="1900" max="2011" id="Yreleased" name="Yreleased" value="1985" size=4>
 <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" id = "Submit" value="Add Game" class = "add games"></p>
 </form>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script type = "text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#add").submit(function(){


                        var name =    this['name'].value;
                        var type =    this['type'].value;
                        var rating =  this['score'].value;
                        var release = this['Yreleased'].value;
                        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&type=' + type + '&rating=' + rating + '&release=' + release;

                    if (name == '' || type == '' || rating == '' || release == ''){
                        alert("please enter some valid data for your game entry");
                    }else
                    $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: "add.php",
                         data: dataString,
                         success: function(){
                           window.location.reload(true);
                          $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                          $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                         }
                    });

           return false;
        }

                                )});

        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a.deletebutton").click(function(){
             var del_id = $(this).attr("id");
             var info = 'id=' + del_id;
             var parent = $(this).parent();
            if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this game? !..There is no Undo")){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    url: "delete.php?" + info,

                    context: document.body,
                    success: function(){

                        $('.p'+del_id).html('deleted');
                        $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                    }
                });
            }
             return false;
     });
 });
 </script>
     </body>
 </html>
```

### add.php

```
<?php
    require('dbconfig.php'); //we cannot continue without this file, thats why using require instead of include

    if(isset($_POST['name']))
    {

    $name=addslashes($_POST['name']);
    $type=addslashes(($_POST['type']));
    $rating=addslashes($_POST['rating']);
    $release=addslashes($_POST['release']);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `games` (`Name`,`Type`,`Rating`,`Release Year`)  VALUES ("'.$name.'", "'.$type.'", "'.$rating.'", "'.$release.'")'; 
    mysql_query( $sql);
    if(!mysql_errno())
    echo " your game has been added to the list of games. ";
    }
?>
```

### delete.php

```
<?php
  require('dbconfig.php'); //we cannot continue without this file, thats why using require instead of include
  if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id=(int)$_GET['id'];
   $sql = 'DELETE FROM `games` WHERE `ID`="'.$id.'"'; //make sure tbale has ID (not id   or Id)
   mysql_query( $sql);
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with this too for a while, if what you're looking for is an ajax type of upload for your images, you'll have to use iframes and then you can send the iframe the image and a unique id of the game in the database so the iframe's script will be to save the image and then save the url of the saved image in the database based on the unique id of the game.

http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is have a file upload form (there should be plenty jquery plugin's that do file uploads and allow you to crop etc) and then you could have the php keep the images in a structure of your choice - e.g. they could all be in one folder or you could store them by letter etc.

Then all you need to do is store the path of the image in the db with the other data and print it out using php.

Might be a bit tricky to do all of that without a single page refresh but I imagine if you take it one step at a time and if you get stuck post a question on each stage on here then you will get there.